# Java - Polymorphism and object class design

Tags: java, polymorphism, extends, instance-variables

I'm trying to practice generics and polymorphism. 
I have a Node class as follows:

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T name;
    public Node[] children;
}
```

Then a generic Tree class:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    public Node<T> root;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to implement a binary tree. A binary tree **is a** tree, thus satisfying **is a** rule of polymorphism.
I'm struggling with how to enforce that nodes in binary trees can have a maximum of two children.

Should I extend node class to Binary node and children array is always initialized to size 2?
If BinaryTree extends Tree, how do I place the restriction on the *children* member variable?

It's like I am trying to make:

```
BinryTree extends Tree
BinaryTreeNode extends Node
```

Where Node is a member variable in Tree and BinaryTreeNode is a member variable in BinaryTree. What would be a proper design?

Comment: Give it a field for each of the "left" and "right" children. Aside from anything, this would avoid the issue of a raw-typed array.

Comment: ^ maybe `Node` shouldn't have children at all.

Comment: I was thinking to have left to return children[0] and right to return children[1]. Trying to see if I can maintain some type of class-hierarchy.

Comment: Your BinaryTree may extend Tree but it doesn't need to instantiate Node instances.  Consider creating a custom BinaryTreeNode that extends Node.  The BinaryTreeNode will handle limiting itself to two children.  Note that BinaryTreeNode may need to override some behavior of its parent to limit access to the internal array.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
public class Node<T> {
public T name;
public Node[] children;
public Node(int numOfChildren) { children = new Node[numOfChildren]; }
}
```

If you would like the node to hold 2 nodes call the constructor with 2, That way children will hold up to 2 nodes. Also it would be better to use encapsulation and make children private and provide accessibility with getters and setters:

```
public class Node<T> {
public T name;
private Node[] children;

public Node(int numOfChildren) { children = new Node[numOfChildren]; }

public Node[] getChildren() { return children; }
}
```

Comment: Tree class is also using Node and hoping to be more generic and be able to create Trees other than BinaryTree as well.

Comment: I was thinking around the same lines; however, this doesn't restrict BinaryTree to have a node with more than 2 children nodes.

Comment: The concept here is right. I would create an abstract class Node and Tree with protected constructors that accept the number of children as parameter. Then have implementations of those classes BinaryTree and BinaryNode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with from the above suggestions.
Node class:

```
public abstract class Node<T> {
    protected T value;
    protected Node[] children;
}
```

BinaryTreeNode

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> extends Node {
    public BinaryTreeNode() {
        children = new BinaryTreeNode[2];
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        children = new BinaryTreeNode[2];
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return (T)value;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode left() {
        return (BinaryTreeNode)children[0];
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode right() {
        return (BinaryTreeNode) children[1];
    }

    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<T> leftNode) {
        children[0] = leftNode;
    }

    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<T> rightNode) {
        children[1] = rightNode;
    }
}
```

Tree Class:

```
public abstract class Tree<T> {
    public Node<T> root;
}
```

BinaryTree:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> extends Tree<T> {

    public BinaryTree() {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<>();
    }

    public void visit(Node node) {
        System.out.println(node.value);
    }

    public void inOrderTraversal(BinaryTreeNode node) {
        if(node != null) {
            inOrderTraversal(node.left());
            visit(node);
            inOrderTraversal(node.right());
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for lengthy comment. Thankful for any feedback on improving design.